# Why does code in constructor not run when called from another file?

Tags: c++, class, constructor

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
    
#include "shreeman.h"
    
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    
    Shreeman object;
}
```

**shreeman.h**

```
#ifndef SHREEMAN_H
#define SHREEMAN_H
    
    
class Shreeman
{
    public:
        shreeman();
};
    
#endif // SHREEMAN_H
```

**shreeman.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shreeman.h"

using namespace std;

Shreeman::shreeman()
{
    cout<<"Hello Hello"<<endl;

}
```

Why does this code not output "Hello Hello"? I have created an object in the main.cpp file, yet nothing is printed in the console.

Comment: You posted `shreeman.h` twice, and didn't post `shreeman.cpp`.

Comment: `shreeman` is not a constructor for `Shreeman`.

Comment: You misspelled the name of the constructor - it has a lowercase `s` instead of an uppercase `S` (and I expect your compiler at least gave a warning)?

Comment: Please post real code. `#include <iostream\>` would never work.

Comment: I'm sorry I am new to stack overflow, now I have put it correctly.

Comment: @UnholySheep it doesn't give a warning, but when I used capital S it works. Why can't I use small letter s?

Comment: @Shreeman24 How does `shreeman();` in your class definition even compile?

Comment: @Shreeman24 We're having trouble helping you because you're posted what you think the code is, rather than what it actually is, and the difference is important. Please produce a [Minimal Reproducible Example](How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the `Shreeman` class, `shreeman()` (lowercase `s`) is not a valid constructor, it is just a member method.  It needs to be renamed to `Shreeman()` (uppercase `S`) to be a construcor (the compiler should have warned you about that).  C++ is case-sensitive, and a constructor name needs to match the class name *exactly*, case and all.

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "shreeman.h"
    
int main()
{    
    Shreeman object;
}
```

shreeman.h

```
#ifndef SHREEMAN_H
#define SHREEMAN_H
    
class Shreeman
{
    public:
        Shreeman();
};
    
#endif // SHREEMAN_H
```

shreeman.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "shreeman.h"

using namespace std;

Shreeman::Shreeman()
{
    cout << "Hello Hello" << endl;
}
```

Comment: It shouldn't compile without the return type tough, no?

Comment: @Shreeman24 So you totally missed to tell us about the compiler errors??

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I am using Codeblocks and it compiles normally.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe What return type?  A comstructor does not have a return type. And `main()` (and only `main()`) with an `int` return type has a special rule that allows a `return` statement to be omitted.

Comment: @RemyLebeau He means in the OP's code.  You implied that `shreeman();` was a member that was _not_ a constructor, but that would mean it required a return type, which it did not have.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ My compiler returned nothing when I used smaller case s. So the code inside the constructor was not outputted.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe I said no such thing.  But if a return type was omitted on a method declaration, the compile would simply default it to `int` and should have emitted a warning

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe permissive mode of gcc/noncompliant mode of VS would allow this

Comment: @MooingDuck So if I used shreeman() instead of Shreeman(), then I would need to say int shreeman() for example, and then return something right?

Comment: @RemyLebeau _"But if a return type was omitted on a method declaration, the compile would simply default it to int and should have emitted a warning"_ Hmmm strange, errors even without `-Wall -pedantic` here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9a63f3ee7d6de44b

Comment: @RemyLebeau I am using GNU GCC compiler. When I built and run my code, the compiler did not show any error. Only when I changed s to capital S did "Hello Hello" get outputted.

Comment: @Shreeman24 CodeBlocks uses MinGW GCC as toolchain, correct? What's the GCC version you currently have?

Comment: I am really new to C++ so it takes a while for me to understand classes :)

Comment: @Shreeman24 That's no excuse to ignore warning or error messages though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ There was no error message on my compiler and the original code ran normally. It did not output anything until I changed to capital S

Comment: @Shreeman24 Can you copy the code from my link above into a new project on your machine, compile it and show us the output please? (Best do that as another proof in your quesiton)

Comment: @Shreeman24 "*There was no error message on my compiler*" - there should have been a *warning*, at least. If not, then I question your compiler. "*the original code ran normally*" - it wouldn't in standard C++ ([demo](https://ideone.com/clZdMH)), so the code must be utilizing a vendor-specific compiler extension. "*It did not output anything until I changed to capital S*" - right, because `shreeman()` is just a method, that you are not calling, eg: `Shreeman object; object.shreeman();`.  `Shreeman()` is a constructor, that is called automatically.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The output is `"Hello from GCC 8.1.0 !`

Comment: @Shreeman24 Well, that's a pretty old GCC version. I recommend to update to the latest stable one. I guess that version you have is still packaged with CodeBlocks, which seems to be notorious for being poorly maintained. You should have the MinGW Installer, wich makes it easy for you to download and install the lastest GCC packages. Also there are other (better) free IDE's you can use, but each of them has it's own disadvantages, and need at least some basic knowledge to set it up correctly.

Comment: The latest one is 6.3.0 or something.